# Get max keys of a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

If I have:

```
dicts = [{'a': 4,'b': 7,'c': 9}, 
         {'a': 2,'b': 1,'c': 10}, 
         {'a': 11,'b': 3,'c': 2}]
```

How can I get the maximum keys only, like this:

```
{'a': 11,'c': 10,'b': 7}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`collection.Counter()` objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) instead, or convert your dictionaries:

```
from collections import Counter

result = Counter()
for d in dicts:
    result |= Counter(d)
```

or even:

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import or_

result = reduce(or_, map(Counter, dicts), Counter())
```

`Counter` objects support finding the maximum per key natively through the `|` operation; `&` gives you the minimum.

Demo:

```
>>> result = Counter()
>>> for d in dicts:
...     result |= Counter(d)
... 
>>> result
Counter({'a': 11, 'c': 10, 'b': 7})
```

or using the `reduce()` version:

```
>>> reduce(or_, map(Counter, dicts), Counter())
Counter({'a': 11, 'c': 10, 'b': 7})
```

Comment: +1 This looks a lot nicer, although I imagine it would have slightly more overhead (creating a new `Counter` each time)

Comment: Yes, the OP would be better off starting out with Counters to begin with.

Comment: And creating a Counter from a dict where the Counter is empty uses a straight `dict.update()` call, so it's not *too* bad.

Comment: Too bad `Counter` doesn't implement `__ior__`, not sure why

Comment: This is a ridiculously neat solution.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> dicts = [{'a': 4,'b': 7,'c': 9}, 
...          {'a': 2,'b': 1,'c': 10}, 
...          {'a': 11,'b': 3,'c': 2}]
>>> {letter: max(d[letter] for d in dicts) for letter in dicts[0]}
{'a': 11, 'c': 10, 'b': 7}
```

Comment: I like this solution. Feels very pythonic.

Comment: @jamylak I thought so initially also but they are all `number of letters` * `number of dicts in list`. So it shouldn't be any worse than other solutions.

Comment: @Jared Oh I misread your solution, it does assume the dicts have the same letters though, which is a fine assumption, +1 from me (this would have to be the fastest too then)

Answer (score 1):

```
dicts = [{'a': 4,'b': 7,'c': 9}, 
             {'a': 2,'b': 1,'c': 10}, 
             {'a': 11,'b': 3,'c': 2}]

def get_max(dicts):
    res = {}
    for d in dicts:
        for k in d:
            res[k] = max(res.get(k, float('-inf')), d[k])
    return res

>>> get_max(dicts)
{'a': 11, 'c': 10, 'b': 7}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
dicts = [{'a': 4,'b': 7,'c': 9}, 
         {'a': 2,'b': 1,'c': 10}, 
         {'a': 11,'b': 3,'c': 2}]

max_keys= {}

for d in dicts:
    for k, v in d.items():
        max_keys.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

for k in max_keys:
    max_keys[k] = max(max_keys[k])
```